# How to append slick arrows inside the dots list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

How can I append the slick-arrow inside the slick-dots ul list? 
I would like to have a result like this:

**My jQuery Code**

```
$(".my-slider").slick({
  arrows: true,
  pauseOnDotsHover: true,
  accessibility: true,
  responsive: [{
    arrows: false,
    breakpoint: 1024,
    nextArrow: $('.slick-dots .next'),
    prevArrow: $('.slick-dots .previous')
  }]
});
$("<li class='next'></li>").prependTo(".slick-dots");
$("<li class='previous'></li>").appendTo(".slick-dots");
```

**My HTML Result**

```
<ul class="slick-dots" role="tablist" style="display: block;">
  <li class='next'></li>
  <li class="slick-active"><button type="button" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control00" aria-controls="slick-slide00" aria-label="1 of 5" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true">1</button></li>
  <li><button type="button" id="slick-slide-control01">2</button></li>
  <li><button type="button" id="slick-slide-control02">3</button></li>
  <li><button type="button" id="slick-slide-control03">4</button></li>
  <li><button type="button" id="slick-slide-control04">5</button></li>
  <li class='previous'></li>
</ul>
```

**The Result I want**

```
<ul class="slick-dots" role="tablist" style="display: block;">
  <li><button class="slick-prev slick-arrow" aria-label="Previous" type="button" style="display: block;">Previous</button></li>
  <li class="slick-active"><button type="button" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control00" aria-controls="slick-slide00" aria-label="1 of 5" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true">1</button></li>
  <li><button type="button" id="slick-slide-control01">2</button></li>
  <li><button type="button" id="slick-slide-control02">3</button></li>
  <li><button type="button" id="slick-slide-control03">4</button></li>
  <li><button type="button" id="slick-slide-control04">5</button></li>
  <li><button class="slick-next slick-arrow" aria-label="Next" type="button" style="display: block;">Next</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're posting the result you would like to get, but not your starting point or what you fail to achieve

Comment: @will I added the starting point

Answer (score 12):

I find out that with slick you can create your own divs with your own class names.

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider-controls">
 <button type="button" class="slide-m-prev">prev</button>
 <div class="slide-m-dots"></div>
 <button type="button" class="slide-m-next">next</button>
</div>
```

Then you can call those classes within slick function.

**JS**

```
$(".slides").slick({
      dots: true,
      arrows: true,
      appendDots: $(".slide-m-dots"),
      prevArrow: $(".slide-m-prev"),
      nextArrow: $(".slide-m-next")
    });
```

Comment: This would have the benefit of not interfering with Slick's internal indexing of the "dot" to "slide" relationship.

Comment: This worked and it's great, because applies with Slick documentation/code.
But be aware, that this will fail if you have multiple sliders on one page. In this case look at [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798093/slick-js-appendarrows-doesnt-work-for-multiple-carousels), which solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using a Jquery-based library and I'm not sure when you want this HTML to be added, but assuming that you do this on page load (if you need to do this after the user calls the function slick(), append/prepend in the callback function), you were almost there. Instead of adding `<li class='next'></li>`, add the entire thing as follows:

```
$('<li><button class="slick-prev slick-arrow" aria-label="Previous" type="button" style="display: block;">Previous</button></li>').prependTo('.slick-dots');
```

or different syntax, same result:

```
$('.slick-dots').prepend('<li><button class="slick-prev slick-arrow" aria-label="Previous" type="button" style="display: block;">Previous</button></li>');
```

But why not modify the HTML at its source instead of using a script?

Comment: If you're rearranging DOM elements that Slick itself is creating, I'd recommend you do so in an event handler; Slick exposes its 'init' event (`$('#your-carousel').on('init', function(this_carousel){ doStuff(); })` for just such a purpose. I'd be curious if the "dots" maintain their relationship to the slides of your carousel after you add elements to `.slick-dots` though.

Comment: Looking at their doc and demo here http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick, it seems that <button class="slick-prev slick-arrow" aria-label="Previous" type="button" style="display: block;">Previous</button> is automatically generated, so not sure what the OP is trying to do here.